# Accelerometer and calibration - iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, accelerometer, calibration

I need to use the functionality of an accelerometer in my iPhone game. I just have to move an image by tilting the device. However most videos on YouTube just show the tilt feature that is somehow inverted and forget to include the calibration.

I want the user to calibrate their device to whatever position they're in. Does anyone know how I should get started on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made an app like this once. I'll post it here, but it's for iOS 4...

To calibrate:

```
int tapCount = 0;
- (void)cancelDoubleTap {
    if (tapCount < 2) {
        tapCount = 0;
    }
}
- (void)reset {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:0 forKey:@"X-Calibrate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:0 forKey:@"Y-Calibrate"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reset!" message:@"Calibration reset." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay." otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
- (void)calibrate {
    if (tapCount == 3) {
        tapCount = 0;
        return;
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:accelX forKey:@"X-Calibrate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:accelY forKey:@"Y-Calibrate"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Calibrated!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Calibrated to: %.2f %.2f.", accelX, accelY] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay." otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    tapCount = 0;
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(cancelDoubleTap) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    tapCount ++;
    if (tapCount == 3) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self reset];
        return;
    }
    if (tapCount == 2) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(calibrate) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }  
}
```

And...

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
    but = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:window.frame];
    [but addTarget:self action:@selector(touchesEnded:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [window addSubview:but];
     // Override point for customization after application launch.
    box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.window.center.x - 50, self.window.center.y - 50, 100, 100)];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    box.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.75];
    [window addSubview:box];
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:(1/100.0)];
    slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 438, 280, 22)];
    [slider setMinimumValue:2.0];
    [slider setMaximumValue:50.0];
    [window addSubview:slider];
    return YES;
 }
```

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TilterAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAccelerometerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UIView *box;
    UISlider *slider;
    UIButton *but;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *but;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *box;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Move code:

```
 - (void)moveBoxByX:(float)x byY:(float)y {
    float newX = box.center.x + x;
    float newY = box.center.y + y;
    if (newX < 50)
        newX = 50;
    if (newX > 270)
        newX = 270;
    if (newY < 50)
        newY = 50;
    if (newY > 430)
        newY = 430;
    box.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
}
```

Should work most of the time.

Comment: THANKS!!  I'm a developer too, so I have the 4.0 firmware as well. I'll check it out!

Comment: Sorry can't give the bounty until 23 hrs later :(. But i'll make sure I give it to you!

Comment: Very useful answer. I would give you an up-vote, but I've reached my daily voting limit :(

Comment: Old thread but what if we wanted to calibrate it from another view controller, how would that work. Also is this code for a landscape app or portrait?

Comment: Implement UIAccelerometerDelegate in the separate class, or call the method to the original class with the delegate. Since it uses user defaults, it should then be accessible from any class. Also, it is regardless of the landscape/portrait.