# How to calibrate UIAccelerometer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, accelerometer, calibration

I am trying to calibrate my `UIAccelerometer` from ViewA but my Game view is ViewB. *So pretty much what I want to achieve is lets say the user is playing on their side, I want my game to act like if they were playing while sitting up in a normal position.*

So in ViewA would I do something like so?:

```
float accelX = (acceleration.x - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"value1"]);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:accelX forKey:@"value1"];
```

Then in my Game class would I do this in my UIAccelerometer delegate method?:

```
float accelX = (acceleration.x - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"X-Calibrate"]);
//Low Pass Filter
rollingX = (accelX * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    AccelPoint.x += (rollingX*50);
```

Then I would do something like:

```
mySprite.position = ccp(accelX, yValue);
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit**: New code for ViewB, will I still need some form of friction now?

```
    rollingX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));     

AccelPoint.x += (rollingX*50);
```

Then after that code I would set the position of my object.

Comment: Have you tried this? If so, what behaviour do you see?

Comment: Yes I have tried this and it seems as if there is no calibration at all. Is this how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in this question appears to be calibrating in a similar manner to what you've described: [Accelerometer & Calibration - iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045551/accelerometer-calibration-iphone-sdk)

Your example code for View A:

```
float accelX = (acceleration.x - [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"value1"]);
```

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:accelX forKey:@"value1"];

This will be storing a pre-calibrated value. So the effect of the calibration will be minimised if you've ever calibrated before.

I think just:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:acceleration.x forKey:@"value1"];
```

Might be more what you're after. This way you'll be removing the entire effect of gravity in the user's starting position.

Your code for View B seems fine, although bear in mind this will allow the speed of your character to increase indefinitely. Consider adding some form of friction.

Comment: AccelX is supposed to be accelX :) Anyway I think I only need calibration on the X-Axis since my game is only portrait and the character is only moved by the accelerometer on the X Axis.

Comment: The only motion that the accelerometer handles for me is moving my character left or right and that's it.

Comment: But what motion do you make to move your character left and right?

Comment: Right, with you now. Updated my answer with something you could try.

Comment: Ok. I don't want to remove the gravity though, I need to keep that! :) Also are you saying that if I calibrate again after another calibration, the old value will be overwritten?

Comment: This won't remove the gravity entirely, just calibrate x to zero (I should point out I haven't tested this). If you calibrate again after calibration, you're in a totally different initial state, so the old value no longer applies. Overwriting any old calibration is fine.

Comment: Thanks! Also was my game class code ok for applying the nsuserdefaults calibrate value to the accelerometer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5534/discussion-between-tom-elliott-and-ibrad-apps)

Comment: hmm there seems to be an issue, when I go and calibrate it, the Game view reflects as if the player was in the regular position rather than the calibrated position. Any ideas?